# jQuery Flot: Adjust xaxis zoom in/out to calendar

Tags: flot

Using `jquery.flot.navigate.js` I can have flot zoom in/out on mouse wheel/ double click by specified amount (e.g. x1.5). What I need, is zoom by calender. By that I mean zooming in/out by the boundaries of hour/day/week/month/year.

Is there any way to achieve a callback/ interaction with the navigate plugin or custom solution?

Comment: Sounds like you want a "zoomable" date time x-axis.  Is [this what you](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/selection/index.html) are after?

Comment: Indeed, but with zoom steps locked to calendar "boundaries". I'm building one now based on jquery.flot.navigate.js

Answer (score 0):

Solved by modifying jquery.flot.navigate.js to call a callback function after adjusting axis min/max due to scale/pan/double-click. The callback can then further adjust the zoom boundaries as needed before the chart is redrawn.